# How to find the average over the value of each object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have an array of objects

```
let data = [
  { start:  {a: 1, b: 2}, end: {c: 11, d: 12}, avg: 100 },
  { start:  {a: 3, b: 4}, end: {c: 13, d: 14}, avg: 200 },
  { start:  {a: 5, b: 6}, end: {c: 15, d: 16}, avg: 300 },
];
```

I know how to find the average value if data is listed in the array separated by commas.

`const arrAvg = data.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / data.length`

But my task is to find the average value of all objects and display data from the nested start and end objects.
More or less like this:

```
ad and cd average: avg
```

Comment: by average of all objects you mean, the average of the `avg` property of each object? In this example, would 200, right?

Comment: If my above comment is correct, all you need is to add `.avg` after the b variable:
`a + b.avg, 0)...` But anyway, your question is not totally clear

Comment: @CalvinNunes That's right, in this example, all data related to avg 200 should be displayed as this match, to the most average value

Comment: @CalvinNunes Ok, it works, but how do I output the `ab cd` data corresponding to my object?

Comment: I didn't understand, please, based on your example, can you show what is the exepected values/result ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes
console.log(...);
start: 3 4 end: 13 14 average = 200

Comment: what is formula you want to use to calculate the average? avg = (a+b+c+d)/4 ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes None, the abcd data does not count.
I want to find the average from all the data and when I find it, output it and all the data that was in its object

Comment: You will not able to get all avgs with one single `.reduce`. I suggest you to run a for loop, sum all the values from each property (a,b,c, etc...) into and object or array and then divide by the length

Comment: @CalvinNunes Can you help me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single line operation that can do the job.
I think this below code will do the job for you:

```
let data = [
      { start:  {a: 1, b: 2}, end: {c: 11, d: 12}, avg: 100},
      { start:  {a: 3, b: 4}, end: {c: 13, d: 14}, avg: 200},
      { start:  {a: 5, b: 6}, end: {c: 15, d: 16}, avg: 300},
    ];
let out = {
  'a' : 0,
  'b' : 0,
  'c' : 0,
  'd' : 0,
  'avg' : 0}
data.forEach(row => {
  let start = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(row['start']);
  let end = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(row['end']);
  start.forEach(s => { 
    if(typeof(row['start'][s]) == "number") {
      out[s] += row['start'][s];
    }
  });

  end.forEach(e => { 
    if(typeof(row['end'][e]) == "number") {
      out[e] += row['end'][e];
    }
  });

  out['avg'] += row['avg'];
});

console.log(`start: ${out['a']/data.length} ${out['b']/data.length} end: ${out['c']/data.length} ${out['d']/data.length} average: ${out['avg']/data.length}`);
```

Comment: I think you didn't got what OP really want... OP wants the avg value of all `a`, the avg value of all `b`, the avg value of `avg` property, etc.., separatedly

Comment: Hi, thanks for your example, can you remove all calculations from the calculations except my example?

`const arrAvg = array.reduce ((x, y) => x + y.avg, 0) / array.length`

I just want to find the value that is the average of all and display the data that is in the same object with them. No calculations from ʻa b c d` need to be done

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thanks for the explanation! I have edited the code above. Also I agree with you there is no single line code to calculate.